# java, mockito - how can i find out which mocks are called?

Tags: java, mockito

I don't really care *when* the mock is called - pretty much, i'm migrating a bunch of mocks into real world code, because mocks in an integration test are sometimes pretty stupid.

Anyway, here i am with a gigantic class full of mocks setup - but what i really want are for each test to find out which mocks are used.

With mockito, can i get it to, i don't know, "log" or print or something whenever a particular "when" is actually executed?

Comment: So you're saying for every test you setup a bunch of mock objects and you don't know which ones are used when you run a test?

Comment: Yes. Yes i am. Not my code though, so, you know, that would be the issue at hand. Kind of a group effort, that one.

Comment: The next step will be design clean. It looks like your class has too many responsibilities

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Mockito 1.9.0 you can use the [verboseLogging](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/MockSettings.html#verboseLogging%28%29) setting.

For example, this:

```
@Test
public void testLogging() {
  final List<?> mockList = mock(List.class, withSettings().verboseLogging());
  when(mockList.size()).thenReturn(6);

  mockList.size();
}
```

Produces:

> ###### Logging method invocation #1 on mock/spy ######## list.size();    invoked: -> at
>
> soanswers.mockito.LogCalls.testLogging(LogCalls.java:35)    has
>   returned: "0" (java.lang.Integer)
>
> ###### Logging method invocation #2 on mock/spy ########    stubbed: -> at
>
> soanswers.mockito.LogCalls.testLogging(LogCalls.java:35) list.size(); 
>   invoked: -> at
>   soanswers.mockito.LogCalls.testLogging(LogCalls.java:37)    has
>   returned: "6" (java.lang.Integer)

Comment: golden. Fun fact, most of them weren't called. But nobody knew to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

I found an issue on the mockito webpage that suggests this is possible:  http://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=148

> Hi, I've prepared a patch at the following branch. I'd appreciate
>   feedback on anything that needs change.
>
> http://code.google.com/r/muratknecht-mockito-issue148/
>
> The API is as agreed:
>
> Foo foo = mock(Foo.class, withSettings().verboseLogging());
>
> and
>
> Foo foo = mock(Foo.class, withSettings().callback(new
>   RememberingListener()));
>
> The former will print invocation infos to std out. Here an example.
>   This is just a proposal, of course. The location info (-> at ...),
>   however, is simply what the listener gets, and therefor cannot be
>   changed without exposing Location and its fields.
>
> ###### Logging method invocation #3 on mock/spy ######## foo.giveMeSomeString("another string value");    -> at
>
> org.mockitousage.debugging.VerboseLoggingOfInvocationsOnMockTest.usage(VerboseLoggingOfInvocationsOnMockTest.java:154)
>   Will return: >some return value< (java.lang.String)    Method has been
>   stubbed.    -> at
>   org.mockitousage.debugging.VerboseLoggingOfInvocationsOnMockTest.usage(VerboseLoggingOfInvocationsOnMockTest.java:149)
>
> #
>
> The usage-level tests are InvocationListenerCallbackTest and
>   VerboseLoggingOfInvocationsOnMockTest. You may want to have a closer
>   look at the latter (see the class comment). As always with usage-level
>   tests that make assertions regarding the contents of the standard
>   output stream, it gets a bit messy.

I tried it out in one of my tests and it seems to do what you want.  You should use the first example that looks like this:

```
Foo foo = mock(Foo.class, withSettings().verboseLogging());
```